# send mail to users and me Using aws SES

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-ses

I want to send mail to users after they submit their form, like thanks for contacting us we will be in touch with you.
And I have to receive a mail stating all the details users put in my website form.
This mail should be sent after the user submit form.

I am using reactjs and aws, so I researched it can be done using aws SES. But no idea how to do.

Comment: Who closed this? This is a valid use case question.

Comment: After the form has been submitted, you can use the AWS SDK to send an email. There is a Java Spring example that is similar, A form is submitted and then the Amazon DynamoDB API and the Simple Notification Service API is used to send message. Its the same idea. You would use the AWS SDK for  JS - not the Java API.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this with and without AWS SES. Following is one approach that you can take.

1. Amazon API Gateway: Create an API to receive POST requests from Websites Forms.
2. AWS SNS Topics: Configure API Gateway to publish message AWS SNS topic.
3. AWS SNS Subscribers: Create a subscriber in AWS SNS and configure it to send messages to your email address.

Following are articles on AWS that can help you

1. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-proxy-integrate-service/
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-create-subscribe-endpoint-to-topic.html